# JAVA + Postgres Limit connections , how to close it ! FATAL: sorry, too many clients already

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, connection-pooling, release

I need to release connection to postgres

My java application interact with postgres and my problem is when i need to call this function more than 200 time postgres crashes , normal thing ... because postgres have limited connections and this script leave a connection opened everytime it execute.

```
@Override
    public Object[] getExtrasInfosSource(int idSource) {
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
        final SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) getSessionFactory();
        final Settings settings = sfi.getSettings();
        // Appel du procedure stocké "getExtrasInfosForSource(idSource integer)" au niveau de bd
        sql.append("SELECT * from "+settings.getDefaultSchemaName()+".getExtras_Infos_For_Source(:idSource)");
        SQLQuery query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString());
        query.setInteger("idSource", idSource);
        return (Object[]) query.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();...
```

Can you please tell me how to close the connection opened in postgres from this script to avoid the app crash everytime postgres connections is over loaded.

Comment: Where and how do you open the database connection?

Comment: Via hibernate, if i knew how or where it opens it i would close it instantly after the script below , all i get is the getSession and execute query that opens the connection i want to close

Answer (score 1):

According to [Hibernate's javadocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Session.html) you can call `.close()` on a session.

> close()
>
> End the session by releasing the JDBC connection and cleaning up.

Before returning your query results: `this.getSession().close();`

Comment: Thank for your reply , but this dont work i dont know why but postgres keep the connection oppned every time then it crash the app after his max connection limit is overloaded

Comment: WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 53300
ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - FATAL: d?sol?, trop de clients sont d?j? connect?s
WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 53300
ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter - FATAL: d?sol?, trop de clients sont d?j? connect?s
ERROR ExceptionMappingInterceptor - Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection

Comment: here what you told me

sql.append("SELECT * from "+settings.getDefaultSchemaName()+".getExtras_Infos_For_Source(:idSource)");
  SQLQuery query = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql.toString());
  query.setInteger("idSource", idSource);
  this.getSession().close();
  Object[] result=(Object[]) query.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();

Comment: Try closing the session **after** you get the results back.

Comment: Same thing nothing changes :( the connection at postgres dont close

Comment: It's been a long while since using hibernate, but it seems like your configuration might be an issue. Consider updating your question to include more details about how your connecting to your database. Hopefully someone will see what I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by adding those variables to my server config , it refresh the IDLE connections (or so) opened left in postgresql

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/database"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DBA"
              username="DBA"
              password="DBA"
              initialSize="34"
              maxActive="80"
              maxIdle="5"

              timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1000"
              minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="2000"
              validationQuery="SELECT 1"
              validationInterval="3000"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              removeAbandoned="true"
              removeAbandonedTimeout="3"/>  

</Context>
```